# My project page information won't load when I'm logged in. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am still working on this page, but I'm stuck on making everything display when I'm logged in. Basically, what is suppose to happen, is it's suppose to display the HTML table with all project information, regardless of if I'm logged in or not. When I am logged in, the table headers display, but none of the open projects. I've been trying to figure out why this is happening, but I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point...

```
<?php
include_once TEMPLATE_PATH.'/site/helper/format.php';


$projects = $SOUP->get('projects', array());
$user = $SOUP->get('user', null);
$title = $SOUP->get('title', 'Projects');
$id = $SOUP->get('id', 'projects');

$hasPermission = Session::isLoggedIn();

// $hasPermission = Session::isLoggedIn() || Session::isAdmin(); 
// KEEP WORKING ON THIS SOLUTION
// FOR SOME REASON THE PROJECTS DON'T DISPLAY THEMSELVES WHEN LOGGED IN


$fork = $SOUP->fork();
$fork->set('title', $title);
$fork->set('id', $id);


if($hasPermission) {
    $fork->set('creatable', true);
    $fork->set('createLabel', 'New Projects');
}

$fork->startBlockSet('body');

if($hasPermission) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#<?= $id ?> .createButton').click(function(){
    window.location = '<?= Url::projectNew() ?>';
});

</script>



<?php 
// Commenting out the code here allows the table headers to show, but 
// still won't display the project info, when logged in.
   }

// if(!empty($projects)) {


?>




<!-- FOR SOME REASON THIS ISN'T SHOWING IF YOU ARE LOGGED IN -->
<table class="projects">

    <tr>
        <th style="padding-left: 5px;">Projects</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Deadline</th>
        <th>Members</th> <!-- Change this to Entries -->
        <th>Category</th> 
<!-- This still needs to be echo'd after backend work is done -->
        <th>Reward</th> 
<!-- This still needs to be echo'd after backend work is done -->
        <?php if(!is_null($user)): ?>
        <th>Role</th>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>




<?php
    foreach($projects as $p) {
        echo '<tr>';
        // title and pitch
        echo '<td class="name">';
        echo '<h6>
<a href="'.Url::project($p->getID()).'">'.$p->getTitle().'</a></h6>';
        echo '<p>';



        // THIS CODE WILL DISPLAY THE PITCH UNDER TITLE OF PROJECT
        // $pitch = strip_tags(formatPitch($p->getPitch()));
         //echo substr($pitch,0,70);
         //if(strlen($pitch) > 70)
            // echo "&hellip;";
        // echo '</p>';
       // echo '</td>';





        // status
        $status = formatProjectStatus($p->getStatus());
        echo '<td class="status">'.$status.'</td>';



        // deadline
        $deadline = $p->getDeadline();
        $deadline = (empty($deadline)) ? '--' : formatTimeTag($deadline);
        echo '<td class="deadline">'.$deadline.'</td>';


        // members  
    *** CHANGE THIS TO THE NUMBER OF ENTRIES/CONTRIBUTIONS
        $members = count($p->getAllMembers())+1;
        echo '<td class="members">
    <a href="'.Url::people($p->getID()).'">'.$members.'</a></td>';






        // role


         if(!is_null($user)) {
            $relationship = '';
            if(ProjectUser::isCreator($user->getID(), $p->getID())) {
                $relationship = 'creator';
            } 
            elseif(ProjectUser::isTrusted($user->getID(), $p->getID())) {
                $relationship = 'trusted member';           
            } 
            elseif(ProjectUser::isMember($user->getID(), $p->getID())) {
                $relationship = 'member';
            } 
           elseif(ProjectUser::isFollower($user->getID(),$p->getID()))  {
                $relationship = 'follower';
            }



            echo '<td class="role">'.$relationship.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
     ?>
    </table>
    <?php
     //   } 
     //       else {

     //   echo '<p>(none)</p>';
     //   }


    $fork->endBlockSet();
    $fork->render('site/partial/panel');

    ?>
```

****The code below this point works in conjunction with the code above here, which is contained in a separate file. So, I'm not sure if the issue is contained within this file, or the one above.

```
<?php

class ProjectUser extends DbObject
{
    protected $id;
    protected $userID;
    protected $projectID;
    protected $relationship;

    const DB_TABLE = 'project_user';

    const BANNED = 0;
    const FOLLOWER = 1;
    const MEMBER = 5;
    const TRUSTED = 10;
    const CREATOR = 101;

    // const TRUSTED = 1;
    // const UNTRUSTED = 0;
    //const ORGANIZER = 10;

    public function __construct($args=array())
    {
        $defaultArgs = array(
            'id' => null,
            'user_id' => 0,
            'project_id' => 0,
            'relationship' => 0
    );  

    $args += $defaultArgs;

    $this->id = $args['id'];
    $this->userID = $args['user_id'];
    $this->projectID = $args['project_id'];
    $this->relationship = $args['relationship'];
    }   

    public static function load($id)
    {
        $db = Db::instance();
        $obj = $db->fetch($id, __CLASS__, self::DB_TABLE);
        return $obj;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $db = Db::instance();
    // map database fields to class properties; omit id and dateCreated
    $db_properties = array(
        '    user_id' => $this->userID,
        'project_id' => $this->projectID,
        'relationship' => $this->relationship
    );      
    $db->store($this, __CLASS__, self::DB_TABLE, $db_properties);
    }

    public function delete() {
    $query = "DELETE from ".self::DB_TABLE;
    $query .= " WHERE user_id = ".$this->userID;
    $query .= " AND project_id = ".$this->projectID;

    $db = Db::instance();
    $db->execute($query);
    ObjectCache::remove(get_class($this),$this->id);
    }





     public static function find($userID=null, $projectID=null) {
      if( ($userID === null) ||
            ($projectID === null) ) {
        return null;
      }

        $query = "SELECT id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE;
        $query .= " WHERE user_id = ".$userID;
        $query .= " AND project_id = ".$projectID;

        $db = Db::instance();
        $result = $db->lookup($query);
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
        return null;
        elseif($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            return (self::load($row['id']));
    }

    // used on profile page
    public static function getProjectsByUserID($userID=null,
    $limit=null) {
    if($userID === null) return null;
    $loggedInUserID = Session::getUserID();

    $query = " SELECT pu.project_id AS id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE." pu";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN ".Project::DB_TABLE." p ON";
        $query .= " pu.project_id = p.id";
    $query .= " WHERE pu.user_id = ".$userID;
    $query .= " AND pu.relationship != ".self::BANNED;
        // only show private projects if logged-in user is also a member
    if(!empty($loggedInUserID)) {
        $query .= " AND (p.private = 0";
        $query .= " OR pu.project_id IN (";
            $query .= " SELECT project_id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE;
            $query .= " WHERE user_id = ".$loggedInUserID;
            $query .= " AND relationship != ".self::BANNED;
        $query .= " ))";
        } else {
        $query .= " AND p.private = 0";
        }
        $query .= " ORDER BY p.title ASC";
        if(!empty($limit))
        $query .= " LIMIT ".$limit;

        $db = Db::instance();
        $result = $db->lookup($query);
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) return array();

        $projects = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $projects[$row['id']] = Project::load($row['id']);
        return $projects;   
    }

    public static function getAllMembers($projectID=null) {
        if($projectID === null) return null;

        $query = "SELECT user_id AS id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE." pu";
        $query .= " INNER JOIN ".User::DB_TABLE." u ON ";
        $query .= " pu.user_id = u.id";
        $query .= " WHERE pu.project_id = ".$projectID;
        $query .= " AND (pu.relationship = ".self::MEMBER;
        $query .= " OR pu.relationship = ".self::TRUSTED.')';
        $query .= " ORDER BY u.username ASC";   
        //echo $query.'<br />';

        $db = Db::instance();
        $result = $db->lookup($query);
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) return array();

        $users = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            $users[$row['id']] = User::load($row['id']);
        return $users;          
    }

    public static function getTrusted($projectID=null) {
        return(self::getByProjectID($projectID, self::TRUSTED));
    }

    public static function getMembers($projectID=null) {
        return(self::getByProjectID($projectID, self::MEMBER));
    }   

    public static function getFollowers($projectID=null) {
        return(self::getByProjectID($projectID, self::FOLLOWER));
    }

    public static function getBanned($projectID=null) {
        return(self::getByProjectID($projectID, self::BANNED));
    }

    public static function getBannableUsernames($projectID=null, 
    $term=null) {
        if($projectID === null) return null;

        $query = "SELECT username FROM ".User::DB_TABLE;
        $query .= " WHERE id NOT IN (";
        $query .= " SELECT user_id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE;
        $query .= " WHERE project_id = ".$projectID;
        $query .= " AND relationship = ".self::BANNED; // can't be banned
        $query .= " OR relationship = ".self::CREATOR; // can't be
        creator
        $query .= " )";
        if(!empty($term))
            $query .= " AND username LIKE '%".$term."%'";
        $query .= " ORDER BY username ASC";

        $db = Db::instance();
        $result = $db->lookup($query);
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) return array();

        $usernames = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $usernames[] = $row['username'];
        return $usernames;      
    }

    public static function getTrustedUsernames($projectID=null, 
    $term=null) {
    if($projectID === null) return null;

        $query = "SELECT u.username AS username FROM ".User::DB_TABLE." 
    u"; 
    $query .= " INNER JOIN ".self::DB_TABLE." pu";
    $query .= " ON u.id = pu.user_id";
    $query .= " WHERE pu.project_id = ".$projectID;
    $query .= " AND (pu.relationship = ".self::TRUSTED;
    $query .= " OR pu.relationship = ".self::CREATOR.")";
    if(!empty($term))
         $query .= " AND u.username LIKE '%".$term."%'";        
    $query .= " ORDER BY u.username ASC";

        $db = Db::instance();
    $result = $db->lookup($query);

    if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
        return array();

    $usernames = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            $usernames[] = $row['username'];
    return $usernames;          
    }   

    public static function getUnaffiliatedUsernames($projectID=null,
    $term=null) {
    if($projectID === null) return null;

    $query = "SELECT username FROM ".User::DB_TABLE;    
    $query .= " WHERE id NOT IN (";
        $query .= " SELECT user_id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE;
        $query .= " WHERE project_id = ".$projectID;
    $query .= " )";
    if(!empty($term))
        $query .= " AND username LIKE '%".$term."%'";       
    $query .= " ORDER BY username ASC";

     $db = Db::instance();
    $result = $db->lookup($query);

    if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
        return array();

    $usernames = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $usernames[] = $row['username'];
    return $usernames;          
    }       

    public static function getByProjectID($projectID=null,  
    $relationship=null) {
    if($projectID == null) return null;

    $query = "SELECT user_id AS id FROM ".self::DB_TABLE." pu";
    $query .= " INNER JOIN ".User::DB_TABLE." u ON ";
    $query .= " pu.user_id = u.id";
    $query .= " WHERE pu.project_id = ".$projectID;
    if($relationship !== null) {
        $query .= " AND pu.relationship = ".$relationship;
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY u.username ASC";   
    //echo $query.'<br />';

    $db = Db::instance();
    $result = $db->lookup($query);
    if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) return array();

    $users = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $users[$row['id']] = User::load($row['id']);
        return $users;          
    }

    public static function isCreator($userID=null, $projectID=null) {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID,self::CREATOR));   
    }

    public static function isTrusted($userID=null, $projectID=null) {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID,self::TRUSTED));
    }

    public static function isMember($userID=null, $projectID=null) {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID,self::MEMBER));
    }

    public static function isFollower($userID=null, $projectID=null)
    {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID,self::FOLLOWER));
    }

    public static function isBanned($userID=null, $projectID=null)
    {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID,self::BANNED));
    }

    public static function isAffiliated($userID=null, $projectID=null) {
    return (self::hasRelationship($userID,$projectID));
    }

    // avoid calling this... use one of the aliased functions above 
    //   instead
    public static function hasRelationship($userID=null,
   $projectID=null, $relationship=null) {
    if( ($userID === null) || ($projectID === null) ) return null;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".self::DB_TABLE;
    $query .= " WHERE user_id = ".$userID;
    $query .= " AND project_id = ".$projectID;
    if($relationship !== null)
        $query .= " AND relationship = ".$relationship;
    //echo $query;

    $db = Db::instance();
    $result = $db->lookup($query);
    if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    }


    // --- only getters and setters below here --- //   

    public function getID()
    {
        return ($this->id);
    }

    public function setID($newID)
    {
        $this->id = $newID;
        $this->modified = true;
    }   

    public function getUserID()
    {
        return ($this->userID);
    }

    public function setUserID($newUserID)
    {
    $this->userID = $newUserID;
    $this->modified = true;
    }

    public function getProjectID()
    {
    return ($this->projectID);
    }

    public function setProjectID($newProjectID)
    {
     $this->projectID = $newProjectID;
    $this->modified = true; 
    }

    public function getRelationship()
    {
    return ($this->relationship);
    }

    public function setRelationship($newRelationship)
    {
    $this->relationship = $newRelationship;
    $this->modified = true;
    }

   }
```

Comment: This may or may not be your issue, but I've run into it before when mixing php/html like this, the `{}` brackets get "lost" and rendering ends up not displaying the correct stuff. You should look into [Templating Conditions](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) - basically doing `<?php if(CONDITION): ?> html in here <?php endif; ?>`...etc.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on incase there is a fatal error happening?

Comment: @Rasclatt ...... Yes...

Comment: You are saying that `$projects` should show if logged in or not logged in but has to be not empty, correct?

Comment: @rasclatt all the projects information has to show regardless of if I'm logged in or not.

Comment: If you add `print_r($projects);` right under `$projects = $SOUP->get('projects', array());` does it always populate when you are logged in or logged out?

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi the echo only displays when I'm logged out.

Comment: @Rasclatt - Doing what you suggested:

When logged in I get "Array ( )", displaying over the table that displays all open projects information.

When logged out I get to much code to even display here, showing above the table that displays all open project information.